# Make properties optional in typescript subclass

Tags: typescript

I'm a little new to Typescript, I'm using Typescript 4.4 and I know of Utility types (Pick, Omit, Partial, ...). These however only work on types and interfaces and not on classes. I cannot use interfaces as I'm using TypeGraphQL and that framework expects classes instead of interfaces.

To minimize code duplication, I'm trying to do the following:

```js
class User {
    id!: string;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    email!: string;
    street?:string;
    ... many more fields
}
```

```js
class UserForUpdate extends Partial<User> {} //fails with 'Partial' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

or

```js
class UserForUpdate extends User {
    id?: string; //fails with Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    firstName?: string; //fails with Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    lastName?: string; //fails with Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    email?: string; //fails with Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

I also tried the following:

```js
function forUpdating<T extends { new (...args: any[]) : any, prototype: any }>(ctor: T): Partial<T> & { new (...args: any[]): T } {
    return ctor as any;
}

export class TestUser extends forUpdating(User) {
    // fails with The types of 'prototype.id' are incompatible between these types.
    //   Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    //      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    id?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    email?: string;
}
```

Is there an easy way to make all required properties **of a class** optional?

Comment: DOes it work for you https://tsplay.dev/w2EPYW ?

Comment: But that's not only about about changing properties to optional, you'll also need to change the decorators, right?

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes, decorators also need to be changed off-course. But I first wanted to make it work from a typescipt point of view.

Comment: No, @captain-yossarian - the user in the subclass loses all properties.

Comment: Well, then I don't see how changing types will help you because decorators (actual functions) won't be regenerated magically..

Comment: You're correct - I will create a new question with more context regarding (e.g. the decorators used by TypeGraphQL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class only contains fields I would generally not recomend actually creating a class, you are much better off using an interface

```
class User {
    id!: string;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    email!: string;
    street?:string;
}
interface UserForUpdate extends Partial<User> {}

const user: UserForUpdate = {
    id: "",
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoEsAmAhAFzQQAuSOAdgOYDcm2AZjkuQHJgC2CxpF1eoyzgO3XiXKVadaMOgIuYHCD5TBDbPyQIEZAPxF1M9AF901MsiZhgCOIiQAxAPZJYABzxgrCgB5WVHgwAApgSGQ4YCAAPPDIAHxo5ujALlTk0ACujiTxzm6e3r4AvGjy+CQARFUANGZAA)

If you want to bring in the fields from the interface to  class you can use interface - class merging:

```
class User {
    id!: string;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string; 
    email!: string;
    street?:string;
}
interface UserForUpdate extends Partial<User> {}
class UserForUpdate {

}

const user: UserForUpdate =  new UserForUpdate()
user.email = ""
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoEsAmAhAFzQQAuSOAdgOYDcm2AZjkuQHJgC2CxpF1eoyzgO3XiXKVadaMOgIuYHCD5TBDbPyQIEZAPxF1M9AF901MsiZhgCOIiQAxAPZJYABzxgrCgB5WVHgwAApgSGQ4YCAAPPDIAHxo5qCQMPHObp7evhhm6OjALlTk0ACujiQZru5ePvYAvFhUCADuDsg12fUAFACU6BXIAHSKyiDQTQBEU0A)

Comment: wauw - mind blown away (coming from a Java/.NET developer). I'm really impressed by the interface-class merging. Only a pity that TypeGraphQL does not support it.