# Declaring a class in TypeScript with all the properties of an existing object type

Tags: typescript

A common structure I use in TS is taking a plain JSON object definition and turning it into a class at runtime. For example:

```
export type LessonDef = {
  id: string
  title: string
  slug: string
  shortdesc: string
  explanation: string
  exercises: {
    from: string
    message: string
    translation: string
    hint?: string
    feedback?: { [key: string]: string }
  }[]
}

export class Lesson {
  constructor(readonly def: LessonDef) {
    Object.assign(this, def)
  }

  // Additional methods go here
}
```

The problem is that the type system doesn't understand the result of the `Object.assign`. How can I tell TypeScript that `Lesson` extends the type of `LessonDef`?

Comment: Try to make `def` argument as a `public`, like [here](https://tsplay.dev/wX2MJm). It will create `def` property in `this` with all expected properties. TS does not track mutations, hence compiler is unable to figure out that `this` has been changed

Comment: Alas, I do specifically want all of the properties to be on the top-level object, rather than accessing them through the def.

Comment: ok, you need to declare `LessonDef` as an interface instead of `type`. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOzypW) example

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea you could have overlapping names for interfaces/classes like that! Thanks, with a [slight modification](https://tsplay.dev/mLLnkm) that works perfectly. If you want to write it up as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: To be honest your question is a duplicate. It is been answered by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir but I'm unable to find the link but I remember solution, so I'm not feeling comfortable answering on this question

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032430/make-properties-optional-in-typescript-subclass/70032817#70032817) answer and let me know if you think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Ah that's a similar answer, but the question is different-- I wouldn't have been able to find it while searching for my problem. So I probably wouldn't consider it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70032430/make-properties-optional-in-typescript-subclass/70032817#70032817)

You can merge your class declaration and interface.

Consider this example:

```js
interface Lesson {
    id: string
    title: string
    slug: string
    shortdesc: string
    explanation: string
    exercises: {
        from: string
        message: string
        translation: string
        hint?: string
        feedback?: { [key: string]: string }
    }[]
}

declare let x: Lesson;

class Lesson {
    constructor(def: Lesson) {
        Object.assign(this, def);
    }
}

const result = new Lesson(x)

result.exercises // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WK7YzW)

**@Cerberus** thank you for pointing out my mistake regarding using `{... def}` instead of `def`

However, there is a drawback, you can refer to `this.exercises` before `Object.assign`

```js
class Lesson {
    constructor(def: Lesson) {
        this.exercises //ok, <----- DRAWBACK!
        Object.assign(this, def);
    }
}
```

Comment: "to avoid creating of extra `def` property in `this`" - could you explain this part? AFAIK, `Object.assign` does not even know the name of passed variables, so no extra property would be created.

Comment: @Cerberus you are right, it is my mistake. I have already fixed it. Thank you!